# Avoid Sorting of Values Bar Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

Searching for a way to avoid the automatic sorting by values within the following bar graph:[image]

The goal is to have the x-axis labels as sorting values (e.g., 1950, 1951,...,2001, 2002) instead of the sorting by value in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Add a sort_index() after the value_counts portion of your script.  This should sort the data by the birth year before you plot it.

Should be like.

```
df['birth_year'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar') ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that value_counts returns a series sorted by values.

@jawsem's solution resort by index, as an alternative solution, you can also groupby and count rows :

```
df.groupby('birth_year').size().plot(kind='bar') ......
```